# How to determine cubes which use particular dimension?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Performing changes to dimensions is always a risk for me if I don't know exactly which cubes will be affected. Is there a more elegant way to do this than checking every cube one by one or creating an external documentation?

I would generally like to know if there is a way to do it, because we use a wide range of versions, but especially for **SQL Server 2000** and **2008**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dimensions are actually realted to Measure Groups (whihc belong to cubes, of course)
You can check these realtions with this query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    $SYSTEM.MDSCHEMA_MEASUREGROUP_DIMENSIONS
WHERE   CUBE_NAME = 'YOUR_CUBE_NAME'
```

Comment: This works for me on SQL SERVER 2008 when using `WHERE   [DIMENSION_UNIQUE_NAME] = '[mydimension]'`. I'm a bit confused why i get dimensions inside column `cube_name` like `$DIM YEAR`, this isn't a cube? Do you know a way for SQL server 2000, too? Using this statement fails and google doesn't seem to know an alternative, too.

Comment: Not sure, I imagine it is because it shows relations between MG -> dimensions and the Cube and the Measure Groups, but thats just a guess. No, I wouldn't know a query to SQl 2000

Comment: Thanks, i had some conversations with other SQL Server users and they don't know a way, too. Looks like there was no way implemented to do it. I'll leave the question open a bit longer, if nobody replies - i'll accept your answer.

Comment: HI, I just read this phase on an article: "A cube also has two or more dimensions: one special Dimension, the Measure Dimension, which contains all the measures from each of the measures groups, and various other dimensions such as time, product, geography, whihc map onto the logical dimensions present in a dimension model"

it seems to answer your question.